# Why one 2-d array cause seg-fault, and another do not?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

There are several ways to define 2-d array.

And I found out that when defining an array using the code below:

```
int arr[2][2];
cout << arr[3][3];
```

this doesn't result in seg-fault. This just prints some dummy value.

On the other hand,

```
int** arr = new int*[2];
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) arr[i] = new int[2];
cout << arr[3][3];
```

this results in seg-fault.

What's the difference between these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static arrays are located in the stack so it can't segfault since the program CAN access its own stack. However you could segfault a static array if you go out of range of the stack.

A dynamic array (pointer) on the other hand is located in the heap. So by going out of range you ask to get a pointer outside your program's dedicated memory emplacements which result in a segfault.

This is called an [Undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Answer (score 3):

Reading uninitialised values is [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). Your program is invalid (both variants) and has *no meaning* when you do that and *any* behaviour is allowed. The compiler is literally allowed to do *anything*. You cannot reason about a program containing UB, don't even try.

Answer (score 0):

You have undefined behavior. Anything can happen. There is no use in speculating why you get these results.

That said, this is likely what's going on:

The first is a continuous block of memory (2*2*sizeof(int)) on your stack, where `arr[3][3]` means read data from 3*3*sizeof(int) bytes after the start of that block.

The other is one block of memory (2*sizeof(int*)) on the heap containing two pointers pointing at two separate blocks of memory on the heap (each 2*sizeof(int)), where `arr[3][3]` means read data from 3*sizeof(int*) bytes after that first block of memory, interpret whatever you find there as a memory address, and then read data from 3*sizeof(int) bytes after that address.